# Vue/Nuxt production on the fly config

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I wonder if there is any way to have static config file in built vue (or nuxt) app, which can be changed and changes are reflected after refresh.

E.g.: I have vue app which is connecting to API endpoint on port 1234. There is another API endpoint but on port 5555. Base url in code would be set to "http://myserver.com:1234/api/". Now I want to use another API endpoint on port 5555. How to achieve this in simple way (if possible).

Update:
I want to slightly correct question. I want to have vue FE app deployed, but one day I want to change base url for api to whatever unknown url. I want something like web.config in asp.net app.

Comment: May this is what you are looking for: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options/#proxy

Comment: You can define environment variable and use theme in your app

Comment: ENV variables cannot be edited on deployed app if I am not wrong. I just want to have deployed vue app on server and change some values (in my case it's url to connect to API). I don't want to rebuild the app just to change let's say connection string to whatever url whenever I want.